# Scrapy: CSV output without header

Tags: python, scrapy

When I use the command `scrapy crawl <project> -o <filename.csv>`, I get the output of my `Item` dictionary with headers. This is good. However, I would like scrapy to omit headers if the file already exists. Is scrapy capable of doing this or do I need to implement that functionality?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**EDIT (2022.03.09):**

This answer was created in 2015 and it shows solution for older `Scrapy`

In new `Scrapy` (2.1+) you can use other answer with `'include_headers_line': False`

---

There is `include_headers_line=True` in `CsvItemExporter` but I don't know how to use it directly. http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/exporters.html#csvitemexporter

But you can create own exporter with `include_headers_line=False` in file `exporters.py` (in the same folder as `settings.py` and `items.py`)

```
from scrapy.exporters import CsvItemExporter


class HeadlessCsvItemExporter(CsvItemExporter):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['include_headers_line'] = False
        super(HeadlessCsvItemExporter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Then you have to set this exporter in `settings.py`

```
FEED_EXPORTERS = {
    'csv': 'your_project_name.exporters.HeadlessCsvItemExporter',
}
```

And now scrapy should write csv file without headers.

```
scrapy crawl <project> -o <filename.csv>
```

Or you can set

```
FEED_EXPORTERS = {
    'headless': 'your_project_name.exporters.HeadlessCsvItemExporter',
}
```

and get csv without headers only when you use `-t headless`

```
scrapy crawl <project> -o <filename.csv> -t headless
```

ps. don't forget to use your project name in place of `your_project_name` in `setttings.py`

---

**EDIT:**

Now exporter skips headers only if file is not empty (if `file.tell() > 0`)

```
from scrapy.exporters import CsvItemExporter


class HeadlessCsvItemExporter(CsvItemExporter):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        # args[0] is (opened) file handler
        # if file is not empty then skip headers
        if args[0].tell() > 0:
            kwargs['include_headers_line'] = False

        super(HeadlessCsvItemExporter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I do have something similar. I was just wondering if there was an out of the box feature for this.

Answer (score 1):

The following settings.py worked for me.

```
FEEDS = {
    '<filename.csv>': {
        'format': 'csv',
        'item_export_kwargs': {
           'include_headers_line': False,
        },
    }
}
```

Comment: I add that these settings work from version 2.1+