# Scrapy: How to output to csv without column headings?

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm outputting my scrape to a .csv, but am doing so with multiple instances of the same spider to the same .csv. This causes the header to be repeated, which causes problems on database insert.

I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34485789/scrapy-csv-output-without-header) how to get rid of the headers altogether, but his solution for eliminating them only if there's already content in the file doesn't seem to work. I'd just comment there, but my reputation isn't high enough.

Does anyone know how I can print out the column headers to a file only once?

I've tried testing his solution, and it seems that args[0].tell() is always equal to 0, so it never enters the if statement. It seems like this is so close, I just have no idea how to tell if there is content in the file.

Answer (score 0):

I would change the code from the mentioned answer to the following:

from scrapy.exporters import CsvItemExporter

```
class HeadlessCsvItemExporter(CsvItemExporter):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        # args[0] is (opened) file handler
        # if file is not empty then skip headers
        if os.fstat(args[0].fileno()).st_size > 0:
            kwargs['include_headers_line'] = False

        super(HeadlessCsvItemExporter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Alternatively you can do this without using the `os` module:

from scrapy.exporters import CsvItemExporter

```
class HeadlessCsvItemExporter(CsvItemExporter):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        # args[0] is (opened) file handler
        # if file is not empty then skip headers
        args[0].seek(0,2)
        if args[0].tell() > 0:
            kwargs['include_headers_line'] = False

        super(HeadlessCsvItemExporter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

In the `seek` function the first argument is what offset to seek (in this case `0` is nothing) and the second argument `2` means that it should start seeking from the end of the file. The result is that the file handler position jumps to the end of the file and then `tell` works as expected.

Comment: I'm sorry that I never commented on this. I just realized it. I couldn't ever get this to work. I can't quite remember why now though :S I appreciate your willingness to help though!