# Add Scrapy data to csv without the header row

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, scrapy, export-to-csv

We have a local website that tracks the number of people using a certain license. I have create a scraper with that should run every hour. The only issue I have it's creating data that looks like this.

```
active_users,date,time
35,22/03/2022,11:38:30.397745
active_users,date,time
36,22/03/2022,11:44:04.753589
```

the issue I find is that every time `scrapy crawl users` is ran it adds that header. I know scrapy has `CsvItemExporter()` that can remove the header but I'm not too sure how to use it.

I just need the output csv to look like

```
active_users,date,time
35,22/03/2022,11:38:30.397745
36,22/03/2022,11:44:04.753589
```

Comment: hi, perhaps this might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36710262/scrapy-how-to-output-to-csv-without-column-headings

Comment: @jspcal ohh thanks! I also found a related page from the link you sent was also pretty useful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34485789/scrapy-csv-output-without-header?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34485789/scrapy-csv-output-without-header?noredirect=1&lq=1 in case someone comes across this post looking for the same answer. I found the link above pretty useful and solved my issue

Answer (score 1):

If you are using scrapy version 2.4 and above you can directly change this setting when defining the FEED such as below.

```
custom_settings = {"FEEDS": { "items.csv": {"format": "csv", "item_export_kwargs": {"include_headers_line": False}}}}
```

This will append to the contents of the file instead of adding a new header each time.