# Python/Scrapy - Parse results without label, or alternative methods

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, scrapy

I have two scripts - one to scrape URLs from href tags and export to .csv, and one to read from that .csv and fire another scrape using the URLs from that .csv and export the results into a .json.

This is the script that collects the URLs and exports to .csv

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class dgtest2(scrapy.Spider):
  name = 'dgtest2'
  start_urls = ['https://careers.infinity.aero/Careers.aspx']

  custom_settings = {
    'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv',
    'FEED_URI': 'urls.csv'
  }

def parse(self, response):
  for url in response.xpath('//a/@href').getall():
    yield {
      'url': response.urljoin(url),
    }

process = CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(dgtest2)
process.start()
```

The issue I'm having is that the 2nd script is unable to fire because of the label 'url' that sits at the top of the .csv - is there a way to output the URLs without a label?  Or is there a recommended alternative practice?

I took the route of exporting to a .csv and scraping again from it after reading some suggestions that it would be the best practice, rather than exporting to a list internally, but I didn't see much reasoning behind it, and am uncertain if it's the most appropriate choice.

I've tried searching for an answer, but haven't had luck with the 3+ hours I've spent. I tried just using `response.urljoin(url),` and removing `'url':`, but it wouldn't fire.

I tried running an intermediate scrip that just .pops the 1st line off before the 2nd scrape fires - the line does pop off, but the 2nd script doesn't take to it well, and it's overall just a bandage solution that should be better handled.  I ultimately want to consolidate both scripts into one, but this is just the results of the limitations of my current skill level/experience.

Any input would be appreciated it.  Thank you!

Comment: if you read with module `csv` then simply skip first line. If you read with `pandas` then you shouldn't have problem.

Comment: as I know it scrapy can't save without header. It use exporter [CsvItemExporter](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/exporters.html#csvitemexporter) which has option `include_headers_line=True` but there is no option in settings to change it. Long time ago I created exporter which could write without header. But I wouldn't bother this - I would change code which read file and use `if/else` to skip first line or better to skip every line which has only word `url`. (because when you run many times then it may append new data with another line `url`)

Comment: It seems newer Scrapy can set `include_headers_line=False` - see second answer on question [python - Scrapy: CSV output without header - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34485789/scrapy-csv-output-without-header). First answer shows my exporter for older Scrapy

Comment: I'll play around with it and see what I can do.  Thanks guys!